# WindowProc Invocation Timing

Tags: c++, windows, message-queue

I am new to win32 messages. I'd like to know that when a WindowProc is in the middle of processing a message, is it possible for it to be interrupted to process another message? Take the example below, if both [A] and [B] are executed, is it possible for the WindowProc to be interrupted to process the new WM_ACTIVATE and/or WM_ACTIVATEAPP message (as a result of the ShowWindow call) between [A] and [B]? If this is possible, are there any specific circumstances that make it so?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
  _In_ HWND   hwnd,
  _In_ UINT   uMsg,
  _In_ WPARAM wParam,
  _In_ LPARAM lParam
{
    ...
    case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:

            if (wParam == FALSE)
            {
                // [A] Do something that would trigger a WM_ACTIVATE or WM_ACTIVATEAPP message to be queued to the message queue
                ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE);

                // [B] Modify Window Styles
                SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
            }

            break;
    ...
}
```

Thanks for any comments!

Comment: You like the happy answers.  But yes, definitely in the snippet.  ShowWindow() causes the WM_SHOWWINDOW message to be sent to the window.  So inevitably your WM_ACTIVATEAPP message handler will be "interrupted" and your WindowProc() function executes recursively.  This kind of re-entrancy can cause plenty of trouble, including and not limited to this web-site's name.   A generic technique to break the re-entrancy is to use PostMessage to send a message to yourself.  You'll get it back, later, when your UI thread is in a safe place.

Comment: Hmm. So are you saying it's possible for the handler to be interrupted such that it executes [A], goes to handle a different message, and comes back to execute [B]? That seems in contrast to other comments which suggest that the new message won't trigger invocation of the handler until both [A] and [B] are executed.

Comment: I'm not just saying it is possible, I'm saying that it **must** work that way.  The answer you accepted is very inaccurate, messages generated by SendMessage() are never put in the queue but sent directly to the window procedure.  Like WM_SHOWWINDOW and WM_ACTIVATEAPP.  Only messages produced by PostMessage() go into the queue.  Easy to discover by yourself with the debugger btw.  Just set a breakpoint on the ShowWindow call, when it hits set a breakpoint on WindowProc.  You can probably write a much better answer after doing this test.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. Are there any resources on which Windows APIs can result in window messages, and if so, whether it uses direct invocation (i.e. SendMessage) or a queued invocation (i.e. PostMessage)? For example, how to find out ShowWindow can generate direct Window messages? Hopefully this isn't by trial and error...

Comment: Hans has somewhat of a point: if you recursively call a WindowProc (even indirectly), then you indeed have a reentrant WindowProc. But Windows can't and won't suspend your ` WindowProc` at arbitrary points. How would Windows even know what a safe moment would be? There could be all kinds of mutexes locked. Windows _can_ assume it's safe when you are in fact calling `ShowWindow` exactly because it's single-threaded: until `ShowWindow` has returned, your code isn't running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system will **never** call this callback function while it is processing another message simply because all the messages are being put into a queue and (either your code or the framework you use, like `MFC`) are dequeued one by one with no overlaps. Unless one message is finished being processed the control doesn't return back to the dequeueing block.
In fact you can safely treat your `window` code as single-threaded. if you have *multiple* windows running in a single application they are all **serialized** and are still running in a single thread.

In fact you need to create separate threads if you want to run your windows (or workers) in parallel to each other.

Comment: For the "run your windows in parallel to each other" point, this doesn't change the fact that for any given window, all of its messages are still processed serially without any overlaps, correct?

Comment: Correct. Unless you explicitly create multiple threads your Windows program will always run as a single-threaded application. Here by "explicitly" I mean creating threads yourself or using framework that does that for you (for instance - retrieving frame samples from a capturing device like webcam can be done asynchronously and the callback in this case will be called by system with no regards to any other code execution in your main thread)

Answer (score 1):

No. That is the point of **the GUI Thread** - it's a single thread doing one thing at a time. If you're processing messages, you're not calling `GetMessage`.

Comment: But if you send a message during message processing, that will in fact call your message procedure recursively, won't it?  (As per Hans' comments to the question.)